# How to filter comma separated values and exact value from a jQuery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

In my requirement, I have to filter data by expert area. Each row could have one or more expert areas, if it is more then values will be stored in comma separated.

[image]

First I tried to filter data using following way,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns(1).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value="">Select All</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $('#expert').empty().append('<label>Filter by Expert Area:</label>') )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                        column.search(val).draw();
                    } );

                    var nameArr = ['Accounting', 'Audit', 'IT', 'Finance', 'Tax'];
                    nameArr.forEach(function(number) {
                    var optionExists = ($("#language option[value='"+number+"']").length > 0);
                        select.append( '<option value="'+number+'">'+number+'</option>' );
                    }); 

            });
        }
    });
} );
```

Then I had faced issue to filter data for exact word, for example if I select "IT" from the dropdown, I got following results,

[image]

As you can see, even "Audit" row was filtered for "IT" keyword. Therefore I tried to filter result by exact word.

To do that I changed `column.search().draw()` function like below,

```
column.search("(^"+val+"$)",true,false).draw();
```

But then column search can not identify comma separated values, Someone please explain how could I do that?

Running code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3099298/1vykLed8/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `"(^|, )" + val + "(,|$)"` to the search to solve this.

Note: Need to check if val is empty then show all rows.

```
column.search(val ? "(^|, )" + val + "(,|$)" : "", true, false).draw();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1s7kag3j/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom search function that extends the built in defaults and then just call `draw()` in a change event listener

```js
demoInit()

function filterSearch(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  const filterVal = $('#filter').val();
  if (!filterVal) {
    return true;
  }
  const arr = data[1].split(',').map(v => v.trim());
  return arr.includes(filterVal);
}

// extend the search functions
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(filterSearch);

var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#filter').change(function() {
  table.draw();
});

function demoInit() {
  var nameArr = ['Accounting', 'Audit', 'IT', 'Finance', 'Tax'];
  $('#filter').append(nameArr.map(v => new Option(v, v)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<select id="filter">
  <option value=""> -- Filter --</option>
</select>

<table id="example" class="def-table1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Key Areas</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Accounting, Tax</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>IT, Tax</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Audit</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```