# DataTable jquery place input field under table header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am looking for ways to search in DataTable. [this is what is found](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html). I want search boxes to be on top under the header. I tried some thing like this bur failed

can some one help how can I make search boxes on top of data table to filter data.

**html field**

```
<table id="tabular_datas" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>CPU Load</th>
            <th>Memory Utilization</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>CPU Load</td>
            <td>Memory Utilization</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

**JavaScript field**

```
$('#tabular_datas th').append('<tr><td>Time</td><td>CPU Load</td><td>Memory Utilization</td></tr>');

$('#tabular_datas thead th[1]').each(function () {
    console.log('data searching in datatable');
    var title = $(this).text();

    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');

});
```

and then I populate the data table

```
$('#tabular_datas').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    lenChange:true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    // "searching": false,
    buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: 'Activity Log',
            text: 'Export to Excel'
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            title: 'Activity Log',
            text: 'Export to PDF'
        },
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: 'Column Visibility'
        },
    ],
    "info": true,
    "data": data,
    "lengthMenu": [
        [50, 100, -1],
        [50, 100, "All"]
    ],
    initComplete: function () {
        // Apply the search
        this.api()
            .columns()
            .every(function () {
                console.log('obj 1 ');
                var that = this;
                console.log('that : ', that);
                console.log('this.footer() : ', this.footer());


                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
                    console.log('obj 2 ');
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that.search(this.value).draw();
                        console.log('obj 3 ');
                    }
                });
            });
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require, you can take the example in the link you provided and change the jQuery to place the inputs in the `thead`, and attach the events using `this.header()`:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#example thead th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(`<h4>${title}</h4><input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />`);
  });

  // DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      // Apply the search
      this.api()
        .columns()
        .every(function() {
          var that = this;

          $('input', this.header()).on('input', function(e) {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
              that.search(this.value).draw();
            }
          }).on('click', e => e.stopPropagation());
        });
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011-04-25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011-07-25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009-01-12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012-03-29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: when we are filtering numeric values like this for example we have values 60,20,41,20,0 when we enter values like 0 , it should show only 0 not 20

Comment: sir, I am populating data afterward, **  "data": data ** check my code. it will remove the search boxes in start.

Comment: `60,20,41,20,0 when we enter values like 0 , it should show only 0 not 20` in that case you need to create custom search logic for those columns. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67435389/519413) an example of how to do that. If you're having issues adapting that for your specific use case I'd suggest starting a new question.

Comment: `I am populating data afterward,  "data": data check my code. it will remove the search boxes in start` In this case create the `input` elements in the `thead` after you've updated the content of the datatable following your AJAX request.

Comment: `create the input elements in the thead after you've updated the content of the datatable following your AJAX request.`  If I do that it will remove the header and add search boxes there.  I have done this after populating data `    $('#tabular_datas thead th').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });`

Comment: You can easily change the content that's added in the `th`. If you want to keep the heading text, put it outside the `input`. I've edited the answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: in the question my table has sort enable so when I click the input filed it sort the data which I don't want

Comment: Which I fixed in the answer already by using `on('click', e => e.stopPropagation());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249270/discussion-between-jin-phatan-and-rory-mccrossan).